# Button work as a value of input field and that input field work as a value for another input filed in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I create a button that works as a value for the input field and that input fieldwork as a value for another input field.

Because I take value in first input in a format of currency and then it passes the value to the other field without any format.

But the issue is when I click the button it works just on the first input field but does not pass the value to another field immediately until I give the value manually into the first input field.

Also when I click the button input field cannot change the value into the currency format. Kindly tell me the solution.

```js
const num2rs = val => val.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'PKR'
})
document.getElementById("userInput4").addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.value = num2rs(+this.value.replace(/\D/g, ""))
  document.getElementById("Input.price.max").value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "")

})
```

```html
<input name="Input.price" id="Input.price.max" asp-for="Input.maxp" />

<input id="userInput4" placeholder="max" style="height :30px; width:70px; border-style:solid ;border-color: black;border-radius:5px; margin-left:20px;margin-top:5px;">
<input type="button" id="t1" value="5,00,000" class="userbutton w-button" onclick="document.getElementById('userInput4').value = this.value;document.getElementById('max1').value = this.value; RunGame();" style="width:70px;border-color:lightgray;background-color:white;"
/>
```

Comment: Please make the snippet I made you a [mcve] -I added `})` for it to even run

Comment: Also move the inline code into a function

Comment: Sory i am new on  stack. Have any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want to do, but you do not have anything in your post called max1

This one does not give errors

```js
const num2rs = val => val.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'PKR'
})
document.getElementById("userInput4").addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.value = num2rs(+this.value.replace(/\D/g, ""))
  document.getElementById("Input.price.max").value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "")

})
document.getElementById("t1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('userInput4').value = this.value;
  document.getElementById('Input.price.max').value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,"");
  //RunGame();
})
```

```html
<input name="Input.price" id="Input.price.max" asp-for="Input.maxp" />

<input id="userInput4" placeholder="max" style="height :30px; width:70px; border-style:solid ;border-color: black;border-radius:5px; margin-left:20px;margin-top:5px;">
<input type="button" id="t1" value="5,00,000" class="userbutton w-button" style="width:70px;border-color:lightgray;background-color:white;" />
```

Comment: I want to get value without comma in the Input.price  field

Comment: when you put value manually into userInput4 field then it works correctly

Comment: when  click button currency format not working in inputfield4.It works when put value manually